# How to loot non grounded bodies in World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

For many times I have found myself in the following situation:

[image]

How can I loot the body when this situation happens? In this case I can't touch it from the ground or from the top of the rock. I can't loot while flying as well. I have tried to jump, but can't loot while jumping...

So how to loot non grounded bodies?

Comment: I'd suggest better situation awareness.  Pull your targets to a place which will be convenient for you to loot them.  Sometimes you'll still get unlucky.  However, a little control can go a long way.  (I'd say I have had this problem perhaps a half dozen times during the almost three years that I've been mostly solo-ing with over a dozen different character/class/race combinations --- probably close to a quarter million mobs killed)..

Comment: Fetch may work if you're a hunter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes you can fall from the cliffs above and loot the body while falling. It's tricky, but sometimes works. You will likely need to slow down your fall and enable autoloot.

I'm not entirely sure if this still works. It's been a while since I had to try. Usually, though, it's probably not worth the effort.

Answer (score 3):

Engineers can use the [Loot-A-Rang](http://www.wowhead.com/item=60854/loot-a-rang)

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this, really. It's mostly just a case of bad luck -- the enemy died at the precise place where it's too far to reach from above or below.

Answer (score 1):

There's no real way to do this. If you can get on to a ledge above the body and slowly edge your way down, you can sometimes find a point in the scenery where you are able to stand. If you can get close enough, you should be able to loot the body. Its more luck than judgement unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Figured I'd offer an update to this question so that it remains relevant:

Since the release of Mists of Pandaria in 2012 and its introduction of AoE looting, you can simply kite and kill another enemy close to the unlootable corpse and loot the enemy you just killed.